How to install postgres with yum install with different os user
I am trying to install postgres using yum/dnf install: dnf -y install postgresql16-server-16.4
the dnf installer downloads the binaries to /usr/pgsql-16 , which has a symlink to our binary directory location.
When I run the initdb command, it runs fine,
I encounter issues when trying to start the db instance:
pg_ctl -D /db/pgdata/instance -l /db/pglog/newlog.txt start


waiting for server to start....

stopped waiting

pg_ctl: could not start server

Examine the log output

When I look at the logfile in /db/pglog/newlog.txt, I can only see the following
2024-11-15 11:38:04.736 EST [60850] LOG: redirecting log output to logging collector process

2024-11-15 11:38:04.736 EST [60850] HINT: Future log output will appear in directory "log".

Anyone know if it is possible to use a different user other than 'postgres' for owning the postgres instance? I run into no issues when I try the above with the default postgres user.
My data directory and binary directories are both owned by this local user, so not sure why we are getting these errors.

PostgreSQL itself can run as any user. A system-wide installation with yum/apt etc is going to make certain assumptions about users, configuration locations, logging locations etc. You should be able to run initdb and create your own instance as your own user though. You'll need to configure all the directories to be in locations that user can access and also pick a port number that isn't in use.

@RichardHuxton is there a way I can configure where these directories from the yum install (e.g. logging directory) will be located? Or alternatively, is there a list of all the default locations that get created so I can change the ownership on those to match the os user we are using?

Don't mess with the locations used by the system installer. That's just going to cause confusion and problems down the line. If you want to run it as a different user, just run your own instance like I suggested.

you neither told us which user ran initdb nor who started the server.

initdb is run by os_postgres user and the user attempting to start the database instance is also os_postgres. Data and binary directories are owned by this user
